# After hosting PHP file on firebase, it download the file instead of executing it

Tags: php, firebase, host

I make a small website with 2 pages: index.html and page2.php, the index.html contains a button, after clicking on the button, it runs the page2.php code. It works fine locally, but after hosting it on firebase, it download the page2.php file instead of executing it. Please let me know what may be the source of the problem?

Comment: Check permalink of the button.

Comment: What do you mean by _"hosting it on firebase"_? As far as I can tell, Firebase Hosting only serves static content.

Comment: I host the website on Firebase, Firebase offers hosting feature

Comment: @AyaKhalifeh But does Firebase Hosting also offer PHP for dynamic pages?

Comment: `Firebase offers hosting feature`...sure, but there are many different kinds of hosting, which provide many different features. Not all "hosting" provides support for PHP. This is something you need to check _before_ deploying your site to any particular hosting environment.